# Nautilus stopped working after update to 3.6.1

Tags: nautilus

This morning the Ubuntu Update Manager upgraded nautilus to 3.6.1

```
srirangan@pangolin76:~$ nautilus --version
GNOME nautilus 3.6.1
```

after which it has stopped working

```
srirangan@pangolin76:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:2713): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay: 
  assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Switched from Unity to Cinnamon and things worked fine. Of course this is not the actual solution to why Nautilus broke down after update.

Answer (score 8):

Both Ubuntu versions 12.04 and 12.10 use the nautilus 3.4.2. Therefore this (nautilus 3.6.1) can be considered as an "unsupported" version.

My suggestion is to fill a bug against nautilus 3.6.1 in [gnome bugzilla.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/)

**Edited** this answer according to new info in the comments.

Other time, reconsider twice before you add an external and unsupported PPA in you Ubuntu system,
It can brake your system in a blink of an eye. (as did in this case).

Some PPAs updates-upgrades essential system packages and this can result in a very frustrating experience.

To solve your problem open a terminal and remove the ppa with bellow commands

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Interesting, because it was Ubuntu's update manager that prompted the update. Perhaps because I have gnome PPAs added to my software sources.

Surprisingly the very same nautilus 3.6.1 works fine in Cinnamon, I think its just a Unity configuration mess on my machine.

Comment: Yes of course. You have added an unsupported external PPA in your Ubuntu installation that updates-upgrades essential system packages. Other time reconsider twice before you add an external PPA. It might brake your system (as did).