# Issues With Nautilus 3.6 after upgrading from v3.4 12.10

Tags: nautilus

In version 3.6 is that it cannot save the change in view of folders and windows. Everytime I close the window,the view is reset to default. Anyone know any solution or facing the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nautilus 3.6 can be considered as an **unsupported** version - package.

I assume developers had a reason(or reasons) that remained to previous version of nautilus.
I don't think you will receive any official support or answer for unsupported packages.

I suggest you to read this answer [Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: Actually I was not aware of that. Thanx for let me knowing. Is there any way to downgrade to 3.4?

Comment: Yes , look here the first answer : [Nautilus stopped working after update to 3.6.1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204506/nautilus-stopped-working-after-update-to-3-6-1)