# Go to the parent directory in Files/Nautilus Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 12.10, shortcut-keys, directory

In Ubuntu 12.10 (Gnome3) they've removed the "go to parent directory" using <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I was very used to it...

I've seen in source code comments that they've removed this support and there are at least **3 other ways** of achieving the same. I wonder - what are other ways besides the <kbd>Alt + up</kbd>?

Basically, I'd like to find out how to enable the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to go to the parent directory or at least know the shortcut for doing it with one hand (<kbd>Alt + up</kbd> is **useless**).

Comment: What is the version of nautilus ? `nautilus --version`

Comment: GNOME nautilus 3.6.1

Comment: Then look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204506/nautilus-stopped-working-after-update-to-3-6-1 or here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/207248/issues-with-nautilus-3-6-after-upgrading-from-v3-4-12-10

Comment: Aaah, much better! Ol' good look, 'close' button and working backspace. Can you add this as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this answer : [Nautilus stopped working after update to 3.6.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204506/nautilus-stopped-working-after-update-to-3-6-1)

> Both Ubuntu versions 12.04 and 12.10 use the nautilus 3.4.2. Therefore
>   this (nautilus 3.6.1) can be considered as an "unsupported" version.
>
> Some PPAs updates-upgrades essential system packages and this can
>   result in a very frustrating experience.
>
> To solve your problem open a terminal and remove the ppa with bellow
>   commands
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```