# How to revert to pre-12.10 nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 12.10

I currently have nautilus 3.6.1 default installed on my 12.10 installation (gnome3) but I really don't like the loss in features and the slower search speed compared to the version on e.g. 12.04.
How can I revert to an older nautilus version?

thanks in advance,
Broes

Comment: Try reverting Nautilus like this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/210902/how-to-revert-back-to-nautilus-3-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 not use the nautilus 3.6.1 . Is not default installed.

See this question-answer please and revert the nautilus file manager to default.

[Nautilus stopped working after update to 3.6.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204506/nautilus-stopped-working-after-update-to-3-6-1)