# How to revert back to Nautilus 3.4?

Tags: nautilus, 12.10

I installed GNOME DE and the packages and Nautilus got updated to 3.6 but I don't like it.

I removed GNOME DE packages but Nautilus still remains at 3.6.

How can I revert back to 3.4?

Comment: @jokerdino....oooh yeah! done! ;) thanx

Comment: @jokerdino Rather than mark this a duplicate of that closed question, I recommend you make an answer out of your comment and we keep this open. (That question was off-topic when it was asked because 12.10 wasn't out yet, but now it's on-topic so this question should exist and probably be open.)

Comment: @EliahKagan If you haven't noted, I already did add an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it that you have installed Nautilus 3.6 from the GNOME 3 PPA. TO revert, you can just purge the PPA using [ppa-purge [image: Install ppa-purge]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ppa-purge). Run this command to purge the packages from GNOME 3 PPA and you would revert back to the default Nautilus 3.4.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Kill Nautilus

```
sudo killall nautilus
```

Step 2: Install ppa-purge

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Step 3: Purge Nautilus 3.6 repository

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Step 4: Uninstall Nautilus 3.6

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus
```

Step 5: Update apt repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 6: Install Nautilus 3.4

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Comment: After running a "sudo killall nautilus" and repeating this process, Nautilus 3.4.2 was back! Thank you!